# Is this a correct usage of 'let alone' in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, phrases, sentence

**"You cannot take care of yourself, let alone the three of us"**

I just wanted to know whether the phrase let alone is used correctly or not in the above sentence. Please give your opinions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a correct use of the *let alone* construction, which is discussed in this famous paper:

> Fillmore, Kay, and O'Connor, ["Regularity and Idiomaticity in Grammatical Constructions:
>
>      The Case of *Let
>   Alone*"](https://user.phil-fak.uni-duesseldorf.de/~filip/fillmore+88.pdf) , *Language,* Vol 64, No 3 (Sept 1988), pp 501-538.